# Glassfish exception while deploy EAR

Tags: java, glassfish, ear

I have the following package structure: A, B, C, D, E, F

```
A: Enterprise Application Project, includes B, C, D, E
B: Basics for C, D
C, D: Application modules
E: JPA
F: Web project
```

When I try to deploy the EAR file on Glassfish, the following exceptions goes through:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [A] : Cannot resolve reference [Remote ejb-ref name=...Remote 3.x interface =...,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session] because there are [3] ejbs in the application with interface .... Some of the possible causes: 1. The EJB bean class was packaged in an ear lib library (or through any other library mechanism which makes the library visible to all component modules), this makes all the component modules include this bean class indirectly. 2. The EJB bean class was packaged in a component module which references the EJB, either directly or indirectly through Manifest, WEB-INF/lib. The EJB bean class should only be packaged in the declaring ejb module and not the referencing modules. The referencing modules should only include EJB interfaces.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

All module jar/war files are only one time in the EAR.

Has anyone a hint to fix this?

Comment: appears that you are with some duplicated classes packaged all together.. try to open the EAR and see if the class on the error message are duplicated on all these ABCDE

Comment: after,try to delete these duplicated classes and deploy again, see if the error of the class name changed

Comment: I have already checked this. There seems to be only one implementation of the interface in the whole EAR file. (Eclipse: file search -> workspace -> "implements ...") I also unpacked the EAR file and checked, whether the implementation class exists more then one time. I also unpacked the sub packages (jar, war).

Comment: so , another thing to see, try to check if these class on the error message are being loaded by the glashfish , like, it could be an JPA/hibernate class that you're compiling in you project and these class already have on the glashfish as a module

Comment: if you are using maven, could be just a matter of change the scope of the library when compiling

Comment: There is no module deployed with the EJB in the EAR. I only use Maven in the web project. Currently, there is no entry in my web project's pom.xml for the other packages (only for asm, jersey, json).

Comment: maybe you're using the remote interface of session bean  in a wrong way? Try to not implement these three classes you have and see if the message disappears

Comment: I guess I found the problem: The JPA package contains entities and DAOs. The DAOs are Singleton EJBs. I will move the DAOs into a seperate EJB package. I will report if it works. Thanks for your help :-)